# How to prevent developers from maliciously running elevated AWS Lambda functions

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-iam

GoodDev creates AWS function 'DoAnything', and sets it to run with the 'HighPrivilege' role that has elevated access privileges, because she has full access to iam:PassRole.

EvilDev, who works at the same company and shares the same AWS account as GoodDev, has limited iam:PassRole permissions, so he can only assign the 'LowPrivilege' role, which has limited privileges. However, he does have a bunch of Lambda functions that need to be able to run with his lower privilege set, so the admin has set him up with permission to update functions, like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "lambda:UpdateFunctionCode",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:*:123456789:function:*"
        }
    ]
}
```

In this scenario, EvilDev can run his malicious code by overwriting GoodDev's function code with his own code, causing it to run with full access and wreak havoc.

The admin could solve this by restricting EvilDev's UpdateFunctionCode privileges to just a named set of functions, but that means updating his IAM policy every time he wants to create a new function, which happens often, and then multiply this by the number of other similarly restricted users and it's not practical.

Is there any way for an administrator to sandbox EvilDev into updating only functions that run with the 'LowPrivilege' role, and prevent him from updating functions that run with the 'HighPrivilege' role? Ideally, this would be derived from the same set of privileges that PassRole gives access to.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a good use-case for [Attribute Based Access Control (ABAC) in IAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/introduction_attribute-based-access-control.html).

By basing the developers' function update permissions on tags associated with their user/role, you don't need to specify function names in EvilDev's policy, and can still prevent him from updating GoodDev's functions.

This could be further abstracted to include the `iam:PassRole` permission.